# Spring and Open AM security

Tags: security, spring, jakarta-ee, openam

All,
We are building a J2EE application with Spring security, want to use Open AM for generating security tokens. Please suggest the best practices/approach for this. Appreciate if you can provide any links and code samples.

Comment: what are you going to do with the security tokens?

Comment: They are used for authentication/authorization in the services layer. As we are doing it first time, want to get best practices. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please give more detail in your question about how you see it working.

Comment: We have a secured business service (Service2) that is called by another service (Service1). To authenticate, they use openam generated tokens. Consumer of Service1 will generate a token and send it to Service1, which uses to call Service2.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my articles on generic info related to Openam concepts
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/03/sso-for-java-or-net-web-based.html

and Steps to integrate JSF 2 web application with Openam using Spring SAML extension and Spring Security.
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2013/06/integrating-jsf-web-applicataion-with.html

You can follow the same steps for any J2ee based web application. It doesnt matter if its JSF or JSP or Struts based.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great page on the [OpenAM wiki](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/OpenAM+Spring+Security+Integration) which explains how to integrate OpenAM with Spring Security.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.